# Integer valued polynomials and polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

It is well known that the subring $S$ of integer valued polynomials ${\mathbb Q}[x]$ is generated by the binomial functions $P_n={x \choose n}$. One can ask a dual question: how to characterize the polynomial functions ${\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Z}$ which come from an element in ${\mathbb Z}[x]$.
I understand one can write down derivative as a (terminating) series of difference derivatives and thus express each coefficients in terms of values of the polynomial but does this (or another) procedure lead to a neat answer?

There is a necessary condition for a polynomial function $f:{\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Z}$ to come from an element in ${\mathbb Z}[x]$, namely for every $n$ the residue of $f(x) \mod n$ depends only on the residue of $x \mod n$. This necessary condition is not sufficient but I am interested in the subring of elements in $S$ satisfying that necessary condition. Is there a nice set of generators and/or a basis?

Comment: If you know the degree $d$ of your polynomial function, you can determine the coefficients from $f(0), f(1), \ldots, f(d)$ by taking successive differences.  If you don't know the degree, you can't come to a positive conclusion by looking at finitely many values because you can't distinguish between polynomials that happen to be equal at all the points you tested.

Answer (score 15):

In the second paragraph of the post you ask about those integer-valued polynomials $f(x)$ for which $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ is an integer for integers $x\ne y$. The basis in this $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ may be described as follows. For each $n=1,2,\ldots$ define the minimal positive rational $\alpha_n$ such that $\alpha_nx(x-1)\ldots(x-n+1)\in M$. I claim that

1. $\alpha_n={\rm lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)/n!$
2. The polynomials $1,\alpha_1x,\alpha_2x(x-1),\ldots$ form a basis of $M$.

You may read the proof [here](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2011/imc2011-day2-solutions.pdf) (Problem 4, solution 1).

---

Now about characterizing those polynomials which have integer coefficients via the values. This may be done if we generalize the necessary condition $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\in \mathbb{Z}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ as follows:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{f(x_i)}{\prod_{j:j\ne i} (x_i-x_j)}\in \mathbb{Z} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2)
$$
for all distinct integers $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_k$ ((2) reduces to (1) when $k=1$). By Lagrange interpolation formula, the expression in (2) is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the polynomial $g(x)$ which has degree at most $k$ and takes the same values as $f$ at points $x_0,\ldots,x_k$. In other words, $g$ is the remainder of
$f$ modulo $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\ldots (x-x_k)$. So, if $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have $g(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and in particular (2) holds. On the other hand, if (2) holds for $k=\deg f+1$, we see that the leading coefficient of $f$ is integer, so we may subtract the leading term from $f$ and induct, proving that $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: I’m not sure how this answers the original question. I believe the OP was asking which polynomial functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ are given by polynomials in $\mathbb Z[X]$? I think we know what the polynomials are: they’re integer combinations of $X(X-1)...(X-k)$. I believe the question is how can we tell by looking at $f(X)$ whether it has this property. Clearly your condition is not sufficient as you explain there are polynomials with non-integer coefficients satisfying your condition.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas this answers the question in the second paragraph of OP.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I added something about the first part of the question too. But I am not sure that this is what Roman actually needs.

Comment: @FedorPetrov your updated posting fully answers both of my questions, many thanks!

Comment: @FedorPetrov, by the way, the proofs look clear but it would be nice to have a textbook or paper reference, do you know any?

Comment: No, I do not. I would start with looking for "integer-valued polynomials" monograph by Paul-Jean Cahen and Jean-Luc Chabert.